# Transpose Slide Page Number

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

How to transpose the slide page number. In English we write (1/3) meaning the first page of three pages. However, in Arabic we write (3/1).

I tried and came up with this code. Please see attached photo for more clarifications.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,fadings,shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]  {Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade}
\setRTL   

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=Mahogany}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=Mahogany}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge,series=\bfseries}


 \setRTL   
 \raggedleft

 \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{الشريحة الأولى}
  مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.
  \raggedright
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[rotate=90] at (55,12) {\textarabic{حقوق الطبع محفوظة 2018}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}

\section{القسم الأولي}

\begin{frame}[t]{الشريحة الثانية}
 مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{الشريحة الثالثة}
  مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا      مرحبا.مرحبا مرحبا   

  \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single question.

Comment: Can you also please make a MWE that does not depend on special fonts?

Comment: I am sorry. Should I make into separate question?

Comment: Yes, please move questions 2-4 into new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first of your multiple questions:

You can change the `frame numbering` template which is used by metropolos to display the framenumbers

Off-topic:

If you already load the complete `metropolis` theme, you don't need to load outer, inner and font theme in addition.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
%\useoutertheme{metropolis}
%\useinnertheme{metropolis}
%\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=Mahogany}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=Mahogany}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge,series=\bfseries}

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{
    \inserttotalframenumber/\insertframenumber
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If you use the more up-to-date fork `moloch` instead of `metropolis`, you don't have to know any special template names, but instead you can adjust the usual `page number in head/foot` beamer template:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=Mahogany}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=Mahogany}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge,series=\bfseries}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{
    \inserttotalframenumber/\insertframenumber
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```